# Condition in nextUntil toggle in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `nextUntil` method to toggle my table rows values. It is working fine unless in the last link of any levels. For example (please see the table), when I am clicking the Level 1.2.2 (class 3), it is hiding all the bottom rows because it is looking level 3 below which is right. I believe I need a condition to add to achieve this. But don't know how to add condition.

I want when any class level below (less than) from clicked class level, it will stop toggling. Also, is there any other way I can achieve these because it is a slow process.

Here is the code:

```
<table id=test>
  <tr class=1><td>Level 1</td></tr>
  <tr class=2><td>Level 1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Level 1.1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Level 1.1.2</td></tr>
  <tr class=2><td>Level 1.2</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Level 1.2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Level 1.2.2</td></tr>
  <tr class=4><td>Level 1.2.2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=4><td>Level 1.2.2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=1><td>Level 2</td></tr>
  <tr class=2><td>Level 2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Level 2.1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Level 2.1.2</td></tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.3').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.3').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this, or why you're using `nextUntil`. It looks very odd that when clicking 1.2.2, you're hiding 1.2.2.1 (*2) AND 2 AND 2.1. Am I understanding it correctly that what you actually want is that when level N is clicked, N.x should be toggled, and when A.N is clicked, you want A.N.x to be toggled, but not B.x? (Then finally you want to bring back anything hidden whenever a higher level is toggled?) If so I think you'll need to use a different tool for the job.

Comment: @Thor84no, exactly I needed what you saying. Could you kindly give me an working example, I am just started JQuery and think it will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't change your HTML structure, here's an alternative:

```js
$('tr').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var currentLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class')),
    state = $(this).hasClass('hiding'),
    nextEl = $(this).next(),
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  while (currentLevel < nextLevel) {
    nextEl.toggle(state);
    nextEl = nextEl.next();
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('hiding');
});
```

```css
tr[class^="2"] td {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
tr[class^="3"] td {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
tr[class^="4"] td {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Level 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Level 1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Level 1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.2.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="4">
    <td>Level 1.2.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="4">
    <td>Level 1.2.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Level 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Level 2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 2.1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 2.1.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Similar to Thor84no's answer, but simpler, IMO.

Comment: It's certainly tidier. A minor issue is that if you toggle an element, then hide it by toggling its parent, the next click on that element will have no effect (other than fixing the `hiding` class). A second click will then hide it as normal.

Comment: @Thor84no you make a valid point. The `hiding` class should probably be removed from all elements found within the `while` loop :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though this should be a nested HTML structure, it's much easier:

```js
$('li').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children().find('li').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=test>
  <li>
    Level 1
    <ul>
      <li>
        Level 1.1
        <ul>
          <li>
            Level 1.1.1
          </li>
          <li>
            Level 1.1.2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Level 1.2
        <ul>
          <li>
            Level 1.2.1
          </li>
          <li>
            Level 1.2.2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, sorry I cannot change the HTML structure, at this moment it will be difficult to change.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a bit of a play with it and I by no means think this is optimal, but I do think I've been able to tweak what you had to something that at least works. Hopefully it's understandable, but the main principle behind my change is that instead of using `slideToggle` directly on the set returned by `nextUntil`, I use `each` to call a function for every element in that set.

Let me know if any of this requires clarification or improvement.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('tr').click(function () {
    var toggledLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class'));
    var hiding = !$(this).hasClass('hidden');
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.' + toggledLevel).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      var currentLevel = parseInt($this.attr('class'));
      if (currentLevel > toggledLevel) {
          $this.toggle(!hiding);
          $this.removeClass('hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
tr[class^="2"] td {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
tr[class^="3"] td {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
tr[class^="4"] td {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id=test>
  <tr class=1><td>Class 1 - Level 1</td></tr>
  <tr class=2><td>Class 2 - Level 1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Class 3 - Level 1.1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Class 3 - Level 1.1.2</td></tr>
  <tr class=2><td>Class 2 - Level 1.2</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Class 3 - Level 1.2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Class 3 - Level 1.2.2</td></tr>
  <tr class=4><td>Class 4 - Level 1.2.2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=4><td>Class 4 - Level 1.2.2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=1><td>Class 1 - Level 2</td></tr>
  <tr class=2><td>Class 2 - Level 2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Class 3 - Level 2.1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class=3><td>Class 3 - Level 2.1.2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks, its works, but taking a bit time to hide when I am clicking my to level though I have now around 40 records and 3 levels. Is there any way to improve the performance please

Comment: Hi, also I found sometimes when I clicked on the top level, it does not work on the first click, but the second click is worked. Could you please check the performance as well. Many many thanks

Comment: Hi, any advice how can I will improve this

Comment: @arifpervez I'll try to have a look at it later. I did see some minor delays, but I've not seen it not work on the first click. Could it just be an extra long delay? One quick improvement is to get rid of the `$(this)` calls by storing it in a variable, but I'd be surprised if that's a large gain. I'll edit now.

Comment: many thanks for your assistance, the other code provided by Jamie is working, so, its ok now, and thanks again

Comment: @arifpervez No problem. I've done a couple of tweaks anyway. Might as well make it as good as it can be.