# toggleClass not keeping previous click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I found a show/hide function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746844/condition-in-nextuntil-toggle-in-jquery/38763536#38763536) (not my work but similar my problem) and based on that I have created a fiddle demo (https://jsfiddle.net/q7sfeju9/), but it is not working correctly when clicking to show the rows.

In fiddle, if I hide the `Level 1.2` first, then `Level 1.1` and last `Level 1`, working fine. Now, if I click the `Level 1` again, it should show only the `Level 1.1` and `Level 1.2`, not there all sub level. But it is showing all levels and sub levels. If I hide any sub levels, I need those levels should hide until clicked.

Please someone can help me how can I do this.

Thanks in advance

Update:

Please see the code below -

```js
$('tr').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var currentLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class')),
    state = $(this).hasClass('hiding'),
    nextEl = $(this).next(),
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  while (currentLevel < nextLevel) {
    nextEl.toggle(state);
    nextEl = nextEl.next();
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('hiding');
});
```

```css
tr[class^="2"] td {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

tr[class^="3"] td {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

tr[class^="4"] td {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Level 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Level 1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Level 1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 1.2.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="4">
    <td>Level 1.2.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="4">
    <td>Level 1.2.2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Level 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="2">
    <td>Level 2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 2.1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="3">
    <td>Level 2.1.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So, you found a code that is not working as you'd wish. Have you tried to make any change?

Comment: @8odoros, I am new in JQuery, I am not sure what I need to do, any guidance much appreciated, thanks

Comment: I know but it's just 10 lines of code. You should at least try to understand what they do and then to make some changes, show some effort done.Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what state are the children and use if/else to toggle them when appropriate.

Does the following have the desired behaviour? As I understand it, when a level is expanded, only direct sublevels should be shown.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
    $('tr').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var currentLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class')),
    state = $(this).hasClass('hiding'),
    nextEl = $(this).next(),
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  while (currentLevel < nextLevel ) {
    nextEl.toggle();
    nextEl = nextEl.next();
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('hiding');
  hideChildren()
});

// the below function ensures that the children of the previously clicked row remain hidden
function hideChildren() {
$(".hiding").each( function() {
var currentLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class')),
nextEl = $(this).next(),
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  while (currentLevel < nextLevel ) {
      nextEl.hide();
    nextEl = nextEl.next();
    nextLevel = parseInt(nextEl.attr('class'));
  }
})
}
```

```css
tr[class^="2"] td {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
tr[class^="3"] td {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
tr[class^="4"] td {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="test">
      <tr class="1">
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="2">
        <td>Level 1.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Level 1.1.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Level 1.1.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="2">
        <td>Level 1.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Level 1.2.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Level 1.2.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="4">
        <td>Level 1.2.2.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="4">
        <td>Level 1.2.2.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="1">
        <td>Level 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="2">
        <td>Level 2.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Level 2.1.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="3">
        <td>Level 2.1.2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

EDIT: Corrected behaviour according to OP's clarification. I admit, not the most beautiful code I've written, but it works.

Comment: Many thanks Agata, it is working exactly what I am looking for. Thanks again

Comment: One issue, if I leave the children open and click the Level 1, it is hiding the children but I did not hide the children (eg, Level 1.1)

Comment: That's what I wasn't sure about from your description. If playing around with logic which one has to be toggled, doesn't solve it, then I suggest creating another class, say `children-hidden', adding/removing it when the given row is clicked, and checking if it has said class, when clicking on a level higher.

Comment: Ok, check the code snippet now. Should work as you want it.

Comment: Many many thanks for your assistance, works perfectly, thanks